# Apply mod_rewrite in virtual host

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I would like to rewrite url in virtual host.

Virtual directory:

```
htdoc/dev/ , dev.com
```

Syntax in .htaccess in htdoc/dev:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule test.html$ test.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am able to rewrite test.html to test.php in localhost. However, not able to do it in virtual host. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you have **AllowOverride** option set to **All**:

```
<VirtualHost...>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried this but when i restart apache it shows it has syntax error and saids allowoverride not allow here. May i know what happen? thanks.

Comment: @davidlee can you please share how you solved the problem. I'm running into the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be done in httpd.conf in the directory section...

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

...if using Virtual Hosting, you'd need to add the virtual host directory as in...

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/virtual_host_directory">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```